# Add Arrow to Bordermatrix

Tags: bordermatrix

I have the following code for a border Matrix:

```
 $\bordermatrix{%
           & A& B&  C&  D&  E \cr
         CV_{1} & 0.16 & 0.31  & 0.76 & 0.82 & 0.042 \cr
         CV_{2} & 0.35 & 0.54 & 0.21 & 0.12  & 0.48  \cr
         CV_{3} & 0.07& 0.44  & 0.23  & 0.71  & 0.90 6 \cr
         CV_{4} & 0.37  & 0.31  & 0.91  & 0.75 & 0.22 \cr
                 }}$
```

I want to add arrows in the following way (the top one above the indices):

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are other possibilities to achieve this without `tikz`. But with the following, you will get what you want. Note that the arrow above overlaps the stuff that is typeset above the matrix, so maybe you add a `vspace` there. Alike, the arrow on the right overlaps stuff there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

$\bordermatrix{%
  \tikzmark{tl}        & A    & B    & C    & D    & E \tikzmark{tr}\cr
  \tikzmark{bt} CV_{1} & 0.16 & 0.31 & 0.76 & 0.82 & 0.042          \cr
                CV_{2} & 0.35 & 0.54 & 0.21 & 0.12 & 0.48           \cr
                CV_{3} & 0.07 & 0.44 & 0.23 & 0.71 & 0.906          \cr
  \tikzmark{bb} CV_{4} & 0.37 & 0.31 & 0.91 & 0.75 & 0.22           \cr
  }$ 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
  every path/.style={->},
  every node/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=white}]
  \draw ([xshift=23pt,yshift=18pt]pic cs:tl) -- node {1} ([xshift=12pt,yshift=18pt]pic cs:tr);
  \draw ([xshift=-12pt,yshift=8pt]pic cs:bt) -- node {2} ([xshift=-12pt]pic cs:bb);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple code with `pstricks`: I make 4 elements in the matrix nodes,  connect these nodes with lines (with arrows), using an offset, and add a label on these connections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

$ \begin{postscript}
\bordermatrix{%
 & \rnode{A}{A} & B & C & D & \rnode{E}{E} \cr
\rnode[t]{C1}{CV_{1}} & 0.16 & 0.31 & 0.76 & 0.82 & 0.042 \cr
                CV_{2} & 0.35 & 0.54 & 0.21 & 0.12 & 0.48\phantom{0} \cr
                CV_{3} & 0.07 & 0.44 & 0.23 & 0.71 & 0.906 \cr
  \rnode[b]{C4}{CV_{4}} & 0.37 & 0.31 & 0.91 & 0.75 & 0.22\phantom{0} \cr
  }
\psset{framesep=2pt, arrowinset=0.1, fillstyle=solid}
\pcline[offset=3ex]{->}(A)(E)\thput*{\pscirclebox{1}}
\pcline[offset=-4.5ex]{->}(C1)(C4)\tvput*{\pscirclebox[fillstyle=solid]{2}}
  \end{postscript}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Bernard, thank you for your solution as well.